# QGIS 3.22.10: Automatic increment ID with Year from Date Field in PostGIS

Tags: qgis, postgis

In QGIS 3.22.10, I'm working with a PostGIS database layer containing two columns: a Art_ID column (not the primary key) and a date column in the format (yyyy-mm-dd). I need to generate an ID for each object in my QGIS project, incorporating the year from the date column and four additional digits (e.g., 20230000). When adding a new object, this ID should automatically increment (e.g., from 20230000 to 20230001). The data should be non-editable and stored in the database, while the attribute value should be readable in QGIS. In QGIS (attribut-form), my attempt using the expression

```
(year("date_column") * 10000) + right("art_id", 4) + 1
```

isn't dynamic. Alternatively, I'm unsure how to adjust a sequence in PostGIS. How can I create an automatically incrementing ID containing the year from a date column?

Comment: Do you intend to have a sequence starting with `0` for each *year*? What happens if the actual incremental sequence reaches `9999`? Do you plan to use this as a PK/FK? All this is not *exactly* best practice....

Comment: This is less a QGIS or PostGIS question, and more of a PostgreSQL one. You could make an ugly trigger that feeds from multiple year-specific sequences, but that's very off-topic here.